# How do I update the appearance of my JButton when it's clicked?

Tags: java, swing, validation

I'm working on a Java7 Swing "wizard" type of project that needs to validate a web address before continuing on to the next step of the wizard. The validation requires accessing a URL over the internet to verify that expected resources are available. In some cases, this can take a few seconds which can be long enough to confuse a user.

As a quick solution to this, I would like to disable the "next" button and change the display text while the validation is running so the user knows that the wizard is working and not hung up on anything. The problem is that when I add the code to modify the JButton, none of the changes happen until after the validation has completed. This is the case even if I change the button and call `revalidate()` *before* I execute the validation methods.

Here is an excerpt of what I've tried:

```
// create next button
next = new JButton("Next", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/navigate_right.png")));

next.setActionCommand("MYACTION");
next.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Is this the event dispatch thread? "
                + javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        System.out.println("Changing button");

        next.setEnabled(false);
        next.setText("Testing Connection");
        next.getRootPane().revalidate();

        System.out.println("Validating Service");
        boolean isValidLocation = ServiceValidator.serviceExists(locationField.getText());

        // ...etc...
```

When I run this code, the lines "Changing button" and "Validating Service" both get printed before the actual button changes in the display. How can I get the JButton to change before `System.out.println("Validating Service");` is printed?

Comment: Read this and it will answer all your questions and how to fix it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that when I add the code to modify the JButton, none of the changes happen until after the validation has completed.

Your code is executing on the EDT, so you long running code prevents the GUI from repainting itself until the task is finished executing. You need to use a separate Thread for the long running task, maybe a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I recommend this tutorial on this subject: http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why concurrency would be an issue here. I don't need to to run simultaneously, do I? I want to execute one command, and then another. Right?

Comment: You do want them to run simultaneously, you want it to repaint for the user at the same time it is executing your commands. Repainting happens on the EDT.

Comment: I guess what's hanging me up is why it doesn't do it when I call it. If my code is running on the EDT and the repaint runs on EDT, then that indicates to me that it should execute when I call it. Could I get around this by calling a repaint() method directly instead of revalidate()?

Comment: @quakkels Whenever you change a property on a Swing component it executes revalidate() and repaint() for you. The problem is that the repaint() method invokes the RepaintManager and the repaint manager adds the paint request to the END of the EDT so it doesn't get executed until all the other code (ie. your long running task) has finished executing.

Comment: @quakkels Even if the revalidation/repaint in the middle of an event handling worked, you still do not want to freeze the UI while a task is running.

Comment: I guess I knew I had to tackle concurrency in Java sooner or later.